# Replacing a Incremental number text with constant text

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have a XML file I have replace some text like:

```
<instance instanceCode="ZTEST999523" objectCode="ZTEST999523">
<instance instanceCode="ZTEST999523" objectCode="ZTEST999524">
<instance instanceCode="ZTEST999523" objectCode="ZTEST999525">
```

to be replaced as

```
<instance instanceCode="ZTEST999523" objectCode="test">
<instance instanceCode="ZTEST999523" objectCode="test">
<instance instanceCode="ZTEST999523" objectCode="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply search for the following

```
objectCode=".*">
```

and replace with `objectCode="test">`

Before 
[image]

And after it is run

[image]